# $this with $row PHP

Tags: php, row, this

Hi the code below works:

```
private function doPreEventStart {
$row = db_fetch_item("SELECT resultid FROM ResultPackage 
where ResultPackage.slotid like {$this->curSlotId}
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
$this->curResultId = $row['resultid'];
```

However when I add in the following lines:

```
private function doPreEventStart($this->myusers as $user) {
$row = db_fetch_item("SELECT resultid FROM ResultPackage 
where ResultPackage.slotid like {$this->curSlotId}
and ResultPackage.PackageID like {$user->packageid}
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
$this->curResultId = $row['resultid'];
```

It no longer runs on the server. I checked the SQL database and the tables do exist. What could possibly be wrong? Thanks Dobro

Comment: Try and echo the query and then run it through phpmyadmin to see if you get any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the assignment of the parameter in your function is causing issues. Try setting it as a simple parameter in the function definition but use the `$this->myUsers` etc when you call the function.

```
private function doPreEventStart($user) {
    $row = db_fetch_item("SELECT resultid FROM ResultPackage 
        where ResultPackage.slotid like '%{$this->curSlotId}%'
        and ResultPackage.PackageID like '%{$user->packageid}%'
        ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
    $this->curResultId = $row['resultid'];
}
```